# MyBatis Error on Collection of Map.Entry and Map.entrySet()

Tags: java, dictionary, mybatis

assuming we have MyBatis 3.3.0 and MyBatis-Spring 1.2.3 and a simple select query...

```
<select id="testSelect" parameterType="map" resultType="Integer">
    select 1 from dual where
    <foreach collection="properties" index="index" item="item" separator=" and ">
        1 = #{id} AND 'a' = #{item.key,jdbcType=VARCHAR} AND 'b' = #{item.value,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

*(should simple return 1, if the id given is 1 and all key properties given in the collection are "a" and all values "b")*

...which makes a simple `TestMapper` interface method...

```
Integer testSelect(Map<String, Object> arguments);
```

...and we test it with this test method...

```
@Test
public void test_for_bug() {

    final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("id", 1);

    final Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<>();
    entries.put("a", "b");
    parameters.put("properties", entries.entrySet());

    final Integer result = this.testMapper.testSelect(parameters);

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(1);

}
```

...we will get the following error....

> Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property
>   '__frch_item_0.value'.  It was either not specified and/or could not
>   be found for the javaType / jdbcType combination specified.

The reason for that seems to be that the call to `item.value` results in a call of the `value` property of the String itself. Unfortunately, I have no clue, why.

Replacing the `entries.entrySet()` with a `Collection` of custom `Entry` objects (with `key` and `value` property) works fine. Also strange: This only seems to happen inside a `<collection>`, giving a `Map.Entry` directly as a parameter, like...

```
<select id="testSelect" parameterType="map" resultType="Integer">
    select 1 from dual where 'b' = #{entry.value,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
</select>
```

...and...

```
@Test
public void test_for_bug() {

    final Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<>();
    entries.put("a", "b");

    final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("entry", entries.entrySet().iterator().next());

    final Integer result = this.testMapper.testSelect(parameters);

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(1);

}
```

...works.

Has anyone an idea what the problem with Map.EntrySet is here? Any chance to get it fixed somehow? Of course creating a workaround is easy enough, but imho it should not be needed.

Comment: Why you use parameters.put("properties", entries.entrySet())?

Comment: In this case, because it's an easy way to give a <collection> a set of key value pairs from a Map... In other words: Why not? It's either that or convert the Map manually to a Set of Objects with key/value attributes... (And technically, I don't, as I didn't write the original code, I just found the bug there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that the correct way to handle this (documentation update already submitted) is the following (since the developers made some changes a few versions ago):

```
<select id="testSelect" parameterType="map" resultType="Integer">
    select 1 from dual where
    <foreach collection="properties" index="index" item="item" separator=" and ">
        1 = #{id} AND 'a' = #{index,jdbcType=VARCHAR} AND 'b' = #{item,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

The reason is, that `<foreach>` behaves a little bit different for `Iterables`/`Arrays` and `Maps` (and `Iteratable<Map.Entry>` Objects):

- For an `Iterable` or `Array`, `index` is the number of the current iteration and `item` is the element retrieved from the Iterable in this iteration.
- For a `Map` (or `Iterable<Map.Entry>`) `index` is the current entry's key and item is the current entry's `value`

This explains why `item.value` for a `Map<String, String>` leads actually to `String.value` (the `value` is already a `String` - which has a private `char array` member called `value`, so MyBatis is trying to access `String.value` - and fails, because a `char array` is not a mapped type).

Answer (score 0):

You just pass parameter map instead of map.entrySet(), like this

```
parameters.put("properties", entries);
```

and call your mybatis like that

```
<select id="testSelect" parameterType="map" resultType="Integer">
    select 1 from dual where
    <foreach collection="properties.entrySet()" index="index" item="item" separator=" and ">
        1 = #{id} AND 'a' = #{item.key,jdbcType=VARCHAR} AND 'b' = #{item.value,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you actually try that? Because for me, it doesn't change anything at all. Same problem: "Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property..."

Comment: What is your mybatis version? This solution is not support since version 3.2x. Check this issue https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/208

Comment: Tried it with 3.3.1 and could be the same issue, true.